# Which one is the right sentence structure?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Generally I've learned the former, but I want to know if the latter is possible. If either way is possible, is there any difference in meaning?

- Part of what makes watching a movie great is getting ***to see actors bring characters to life.*** (to see~~ : verbid + object + objective complement)
- Part of what makes watching a movie great is getting ***to see that actors bring characters to life.*** (to see~~ : verbid + noun clause)

I'm looking forward to you guys. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please see [Q: Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer?s=0|1.6678)

Comment: Somehow, I feel that using *'that'* is a kind of task allotted to the audience. On the other hand, the sentence without *'that'* seems to be a *natural act*!

Answer (score 5):

Both are fine to say, but they mean different things. *To see actors bring characters to life* means exactly what you expect it to mean -- that you are watching actors as they bring their characters to life.

*To see THAT actors bring characters to life* implies that you are mostly interested in the fact that this is a thing that happens when you watch actors in a movie or a play. You might not even care about what they say or how they act. You might even hate the movie. But you are recognizing the fact that actors do bring characters to life when they act.

Also, I think you are missing another word in the sentence: "Part of what makes watching a movie FUN," or some word like that.

Comment: I omitted the word 'great' between movie and is. I've just edited it. Thank you for pointing out, and your help!

Comment: @J.S.PARK No problem. If you like the answer, please mark it as Accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Ringo, in the best interests of the OP we really shouldn't be encouraging them to accept any answer so soon after posting it  (see the link I posted under the question).